# Rails send multiple files to browser using send_data or send_file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, zip, temporary-files

I am trying to send multiple files to the browser. I cant call send_data for every record like in the code below because i get a double render error. According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8053496/rails-using-send-file-to-send-multiple-files) i need to create the files and zip them so i can send them in one request.

```
@records.each do |r|
  ActiveRecord::Base.include_root_in_json = true
  @json = r.to_json
  a = ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor.new(Rails.application.config.secret_token)
  @json_encrypted = a.encrypt_and_sign(@json)
  send_data @json_encrypted, :filename => "#{r.name}.json" }
end
```

I am creating an array of hashes with the `@json_encrypted` and the `file_name` for each record. My question is how can i create a file for every record and then bundle them into a zip file to then pass that zip file to `send_file`. Or better yet have multiple file download dialogs pop up on the screen. One for each file.

```
file_data = []
@records.each do |r|
    ActiveRecord::Base.include_root_in_json = true
    @json = r.to_json
    a = ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor.new(Rails.application.config.secret_token)
    @json_encrypted = a.encrypt_and_sign(@json)
    file_data << { json_encrypted: @json_encrypted, filename: "#{r.name}.json" }
end
```

Comment: You might want to look into the Rubyzip gem (https://github.com/rubyzip/rubyzip) otherwise if you really want to do multiple single file downloads I think you could do that with some JS on a page where multiple URLs get opened which point to views on your side with corresponding "download forcing" headers.

Comment: @evotopid thanks for the response! Ill look into that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So the issue i was having is that `send_file` does not respond to an ajax call which is how i was posting to that action. I got rid of the ajax, and am sending the necessary data though a hidden_field_tag and submitting it with jquery. The code below creates files for the data, zips them, and passes the zip file to send_data.

```
file_data.each do |hash|
  hash.each do |key, value| 
    if key == :json_encrypted
      @data = value
    elsif key == :filename
      @file_name = value
    end
  end

  name = "#{Rails.root}/export_multiple/#{@file_name}"
  File.open(name, "w+") {|f| f.write(@data)}

  `zip -r export_selected "export_multiple/#{@file_name}"`
  send_file "#{Rails.root}/export_selected.zip", type: "application/zip",  disposition: 'attachment' 
end
```