# Rails 5 send images png from my API rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have an api it has a model Images with two attributes: url, name.
the images are in folder assets/images (just 20 images png), the db table saves the url of the image file, and a custom name, when a user ask for images in my controller i want to send a JSON with all the images together if is possible or separate at least, but the JSON must send the image and its name. How can I do that? Now I am using this controller which send only one image per request without its name.

```
def send_image
  IMAGES_PATH = File.join(Rails.root, "public", "images")
  send_file(File.join(IMAGES_PATH, "image#{params[:img]}.jpg"))
end
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rails using send\_file to send multiple files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8053496/rails-using-send-file-to-send-multiple-files)

Comment: Are you asking to send the binary data of the images, along with their name, in a JSON response? Or are you asking to send multiple images in a single response?

Comment: @bkimble I have an APi which method you recomend me to send the images, my actual methos is working but how can i add the name to the response? or better how can i send all images at once?, thanks

Comment: Without knowing much about your app, I'd first suggest sending the URL of the images to the API requester in a JSON response, and not the actual images. Make it the responsibility of the requester to fetch the images from URLs you provide to them. This will also allow you to send the name of the image, too.